# ffmpeg with high delay in first input stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

My goal is to use ffmpeg to create a stream which contains two other streams (both input streams should be next to each other). In general it works with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://server/live/streamA -i rtmp://server/live/streamB \
    -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=800:ih+10[int];[int][1:v]overlay=400:0[vid]' \
    -map [vid] -f flv - | ffplay -fflags nobuffer -
```

The problem is that streamA has a quite large delay of two to three seconds, i.e. if something happens in streamA it is shown after ~2 seconds. The delay for streamB is moderate.

If I swap the order of the input streams, i.e. "-i .../streamB -i .../streamA" streamB has the high delay and the delay of streamA is moderate. My guess is that this is because the second stream is opened some seconds after the first stream was opened (but I don't know for sure).

How can i fix it so that both streamA and streamB are in real time?

Comment: Try with `-fflags nobuffer -analyzeduration 1M`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: Show your full command

Comment: It seems I put the arguments at the wrong position. Now, I put your arguments before the first `-i`. It also works without `-fflags nobuffer` but I had to set `-analyzeduration 100`. The delay is now ~1s. For `1M` the delay is ~2s.